# Could you pass me ___ remote control for ___ TV please?

Tags: grammar, articles, exam-questions

> Could you pass me _____ remote control for _____ TV please?
>
> a) Ø, Ø
>   b) Ø, the
>   c) the, Ø
>   d) the, the

I guess *d* is correct. What do you think, and why?

[image]

Comment: It's really helpful if you don't just post an image with text in it. The search function can't index text in images, and users with visual impairment can't use screen readers or similar to access it. If you transcribe the text, neither is a problem.

Comment: I also want to remark that nobody ever uses "∅" for "leave blank".

Comment: @MrLister: Can't we use ∅ or Ø to show a zero article? See [Zero (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_(linguistics)).

Comment: @SamBC: You're right! Done!

Comment: @Mike No. According to that link, "∅" is is used in linguistics for a sound that is not pronounced or written. (What kind of sound that could be is left to the imagination of the reader.) It is never meant to convey "don't fill in a word here". For that, we use "leave blank" as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, D is the right answer.

It is a *specific* remote control for a *specific* television, and so the definite article "the" is needed before each.

Common nouns such as "TV" require an article or a determiner. You *could* use the *indefinite* article "a" but this wouldn't really make any sense in your context because it would imply that there are more televisions and remote controls to choose from. You could also say "*my* television" but that would sound a little possessive.

Comment: I might think answer C is also correct. Imagine there are couple of remote controls there and I ask you to pass the one for TV, not for Air-conditioner. Does it make sense?

Comment: @dan I'm assuming that "0" means left blank. "*Pass me the remote control for TV*" makes no sense to me. It sounds like caveman speak, if cavemen had TVs.

Comment: Ok, so what if there are couple of remote controls, one for the TV and the other for AC. How would you express that you want someone to pass you the TV's, not AC's? Thanks!

Comment: @dan Seriously? You say "pass me the remote control for *the* TV".